# Select highest value based on aggregate function - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a GiftSales table, it contains the id of the item (giftId), and the category of that item (categoryId)
I need to get the best selling item for each category.
Right now my query looks like this

```
SELECT giftId, categoryId, COUNT(giftId) as Total
FROM GiftSales
GROUP BY giftId, categoryId
```

And its giving me

```
==================================
|| giftId || categoryId || Total||
==================================
||    1   ||      1     ||   8  ||
==================================
||    2   ||      1     ||   5  ||
==================================
||   23   ||      2     ||   12 ||
==================================
```

I need to only show the highest value per each category, so basically, the table shouldn't contain the second item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using a window function, and dense_rank can be helpful when looking at top selling products by category as you may want to include any ties.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE IDs (
  `gift_id` INTEGER,
  `category_id` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO IDs
  (`gift_id`, `category_id`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1'),
  ('1', '1'),
  ('1', '1'),
  ('1', '1'),
  ('1', '1'),
  ('1', '1'),
  ('1', '1'),
  ('1', '1'),
  ('2', '1'),
  ('2', '1'),
  ('2', '1'),
  ('2', '1'),
  ('2', '1');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select a.category_id,a.gift_id,a.total from (
select
category_id,
gift_id,
count(gift_id) as total,
dense_rank() over (partition by category_id order by count(gift_id) desc) as ranking
from IDs group by 1,2) as a where ranking = 1;
```

| category_id | gift_id | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/itP3mmc9mqNnz2MFLeSToM/0)

Answer (score 2):

Use a window function such as `MAX OVER` per category:

```
select giftid, categoryid, total
from
(
  select 
    giftid,
    categoryid,
    count(*) as total,
    max(count(*)) over (partition by categoryid) as category_max
  from giftsales
  group by giftid, categoryid
) aggregated
where total = category_max;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
SELECT DISTINCT categoryId, MAX(Total) as total FROM(
  SELECT giftId, categoryId, COUNT(giftId) as Total FROM GiftSales GROUP BY giftId, categoryId
) AS T GROUP BY giftId, categoryId;
```

I got it working by using the distinct with the categoryId and since you need the total by category I removed the giftId and everything worked fine :) I used a playground to test this and the playground can be found here -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qsGLKUZyos2ZKTftykkazd/0